# What is the peculiarity of components that are written with a dot in React?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I don't seem to understand, and studying the question gives no clue.

For example, there is a card component.
We create the wrapper, then the body, then the header, then the footer.
These are 4 different components.

In the wrapper, we specify that Card.Body = CardBody
But why? If we add the same component, is it only about readability?

Example:

```
<Card>
   <Card.Body>
   ...
   </Card.Body>
   <Card.Footer>
   ...
   </Card.Footer>
</Card>

//What is difference?
<Card>
   <CardBody>
   ...
   </CardBody>
   <CardFooter>
   ...
   </CardFooter>
</Card>
```

Comment: Sometimes people like to organize related components by putting them in a shared object. It sounds like that's what you're talking about?

Comment: It seems yes, I added the code, and I can not understand why there is a dot. Just for beauty? After all, the components are also located separately.

Comment: Yeah, if it's pointing to the same components either way, then the only difference is aesthetics.

Comment: Less imports, less variables in the scope